# How to pull messages from Google Pub/Sub reliably using Python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

So, the pull method sometimes returns 0 messages even though there are plenty of pending messages in this topic. Am I doing something wrong?

```py
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub
import ast

PROJECT_ID = os.environ['PROJECT_ID']
subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(PROJECT_ID, 'subscription-name')

while True:
  response = subscriber.pull(
    request={
      "subscription": subscription_path,
      "max_messages": 50,
    }
  )

  if not response.received_messages:
    print('❌ no messages in pub/sub')
    break
  
  for msg in response.received_messages:
    
    message_data = ast.literal_eval(msg.message.data.decode('utf-8'))
    # transform data and publish to another topic

  ack_ids = [msg.ack_id for msg in response.received_messages]
  subscriber.acknowledge(
    request={
      "subscription": subscription_path,
      "ack_ids": ack_ids,
    }
  )

print(' No more messages left in the queue. Shutting down...')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return of zero messages is not a good indicator of whether or not there are messages available. The service tries to return messages quickly to the user and if there are no messages immediately available, it may return a response with fewer messages than requested or even zero messages. Sending single pull requests at a time is going to make it unlikely that messages are readily cached and available to send to the client quickly.

The best way to receive messages is to use [asynchronous pull via the client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull). The client libraries use streaming pull, which means there is a persistent connection to the server and messages can be delivered as soon as they are available. You could use the async subscriber and track the amount of time since the last message was received and if sufficient time has passed, shut down the subscriber. However, there would still be the possibility that a message would not be delivered within such a timeframe as there are no end-to-end latency guarantees in Cloud Pub/Sub.

Alternatively, if you must use synchronous pull, then you will want to follow the guidelines in the [synchronous pull documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull): "Note that to achieve low message delivery latency with synchronous pull, it is important to have many simultaneously outstanding pull requests. As the throughput of the topic increases, more pull requests are necessary." This way, there are always requests outstanding to the server ready to receive messages.

Ideally, one leaves the subscriber running continuously so messages can be received quickly whenever they are published. If you want to scale subscribers to zero resources when there are no messages to process, consider using [Google Cloud Functions with Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub).

Comment: It appears to me that pub/sub isn't the best tool for my use case. I'm trying to queue ~10.000.000 pieces of text for NLP processing per month. It takes about 0.5 seconds to process one record. I thought I can use pub/sub as a queue and have, say, 3-instances-large Compute Instances Group. The input data (pieces of text) are coming continuously from other data sources.

Comment: If the input is coming continuously, then Pub/Sub is the right tool for what you are doing. It's just that you need to subscribe in a way that it continuously tries to get messages. If you were going to stop the subscriber when it received zero messages, how were you planning to start it back up again when there are messages to process?

If the data is not continuous and needs to be processed more in a batch style, then writing to GCS and spinning up your compute instances as a cron job may make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

That's not unexpected, pub/sub is a complex distributed system, it doesn't give guarantees towards delivery times, ordering, duplication,...

Note this relevant passage from the docs (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) to handle messages better.

> Note that to achieve low message delivery latency with synchronous
> pull, it is important to have many simultaneously outstanding pull
> requests. As the throughput of the topic increases, more pull requests
> are necessary. In general, asynchronous pull is preferable for
> latency-sensitive applications.